# предсказание продаж на следующий год

Tags: python, r, статистика, статический-анализ

Требуется предсказать продажи на следующий год при условии что в следующем году планируется 4000 TRP

[image]

```
TRP = Target rating point = Целевой рейтинг
TRP_competitor = целевой рейтинг у конкурента
TV spends = затраты денег на TV
```

Некоторые столбцы хорошо коррелируют между собой

```
corr(sales,TRP) = 0,767339893
corr(sales,tv_spends) = 0,655813295
corr(sales,TRP_Competitor) = 0,535788064
corr(TRP,tv_spends) = 0,849711793
corr(TRP,TRP_Competitor) = 0,39609449
corr(tv_spends,TRP_Competitor) = 0,178205839
```

Также продажи хорошо зависят от сезонности

Если бы требовалось предсказать продажи имея остальные столбца, задача решалась бы проще, но к сожалению, и другие столбцы не известны. Подскажите с чего надо начинать решать такие задачи? Или есть ли ссылки, где разбирались похожие задачи? Можно и на питоне и на R или в Excel

Answer (score 1):

*"Если бы требовалось предсказать продажи имея остальные столбца, задача решалась бы проще, но к сожалению, и другие столбцы не известны. Подскажите с чего надо начинать решать такие задачи?"* - это называется "модель с распределенными лагами". По английский -  distributed lag model или расширение этой модели Auto regressive distributed lag model.

Начать можно отсюда

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Распределённый_лаг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3)

https://www.projectguru.in/publications/auto-regressive-distributed-lag-model-ardl/

https://www.reed.edu/economics/parker/312/tschapters/S13_Ch_3.pdf

Серьезно изучаются, в частности, в эконометрии. Поэтому любая серьезная книга по эконометрии может служить основой для изучения темы. Ну, например:

https://institutiones.com/download/lecture/1644-vvedenie-v-regressionnyj-analiz.html

Изучение задачи регрессии с пропущенными данными можно начать отсюда:

https://publications.hse.ru/mirror/pubs/share/folder/21tn35z9vl/direct/92272011

Или в более общем случае

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ru/SSLVMB_sub/statistics_mainhelp_ddita/spss/mva/idh_miss.html